# MySQL SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level reads uncommitted values

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, isolation

My understanding is that with SERIALIZABLE isolation level, I should not see any uncommitted data but my simple prototype output doesn't make sense to me.  The initial value is "ready" and a second connection runs a transaction that sets the value to "set" WITHOUT committing.  Then in the first connection I check the value and I see "set" which is an uncommitted value - not something I should see in SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

Connection 1:

```
set SESSION transaction isolation level SERIALIZABLE;
insert into test (name) values ('ready');
```

Connection 2:

```
SET autocommit = OFF;
set session transaction isolation level SERIALIZABLE;
start transaction;
update test set name = 'set' where id = 1;
-- THERE IS NO COMMIT HERE
```

Connection 1:

```
select * from test; -- shows the single row with 'set' as the value
```

Can someone explain why I'm seeing uncommitted values here?  Is my understanding about isolation levels not correct or maybe is my script flawed?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. Connection 1 shows 'ready' if connection 2 doesn't commit. What is your version? What is the table storage engine?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I am using workbench to talk with mysqld v.8.0.17 on a mac and the DB/tables are using InnoDB

Comment: @PaulSpiegel what version of mysql are u running?

Comment: I've tested on MariaDB 10.3.13 - Don't have MySQL 8 here to test.